# parameter mismatch in the definition

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is a method which is declared as

```
- (void) startmonitoring:(NSDictionary *)dict;
```

and it is called as

```
 [self startmonitoring:dict];
```

and the definition is

```
- (void) startmonitoring:(CLLocation *)currentLocation {

   double latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude ;
double Longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
NSString *radius = @"100";
NSString *regionID = @"GeoFenceTrack";
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude ,Longitude) radius:[radius doubleValue] identifier:regionID];
location = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
location.delegate = self ;
location.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[location startMonitoringForRegion:region];
 }
```

my question is that the parameters are completely different in the function call and function definition. but amazingly, it works in obj-c .. i am trying the same thing in swift and error occurs (which should occur in the case of a parameter mismatch). so can anyone say how it works in obj-c ?

Answer (score 0):

what is the `dict` your are passing ? Is it an NSDictionary with "coordinate" attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works! but why?
before finding any conclusion reading about how messaging works might help. Which is explained in apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html)

In one of the point it is written that any arguments passed to selectors are passed, which explains why your code works in obj-c. not sure about the same for swift is true or not.

> Any arguments passed in the message are also handed to objc_msgSend:
>
> objc_msgSend(receiver, selector, arg1, arg2, ...)
>   The messaging function does everything necessary for dynamic binding:
>
> It first finds the procedure (method implementation) that the selector refers to. Since the same method can be implemented differently by separate classes, the precise procedure that it finds depends on the class of the receiver.
>   It then calls the procedure, passing it the receiving object (a pointer to its data), along with **any arguments** that were specified for the method.
>   Finally, it passes on the return value of the procedure as its own return value.

i hope its helpful and i'm not misleading anyone.